# iis 7.5 http response headers does not work

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I have some static content, jpg, png, in a specific folder.

I woud like set HTTP headers to expire after 30 days.

Using  IIS 7.5 >> http response headers >> Set common header >> Expire web content

I added my value, but I I still get the HTTP header for static content as `(expiration not specified)`.

I already tried to refresh my site in IIS but it did not solve my problem.

Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expiration date for Cached static content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311899/expiration-date-for-cached-static-content)

Answer (score 0):

```
Give this a try with application pool -> ManagedpipelineMode : **Classic**
 <system.webServer>
   <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00"  cacheControlCustom="public"/>
    </staticContent> 
 </system.webServer>
```

also you can check how to configure it in ui
http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache