# Expiration date for Cached static content

Tags: iis, iis-7, header, web-config

I use asp.net c# 4 and IIS 7.5.

I need to set the header for my static content on my website for caching PUBLIC for 14 days.

At the moment I use this setting in my web.config

```
  <staticContent>
            <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="14.00:00:00" />
        </staticContent>
```

As result I get a header `Cache-Control:max-age=1209600`

I'm testing my site with https://developers.google.com/pagespeed/ and I still get an `(expiration not specified)`

What I missing in my web.config to get the "Expires" attributes us output?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Expires" HTTP header was deprecated in HTTP 1.1 -- it's only needed by old HTTP 1.0 clients (or to satisfy tools that don't know any better).

If you really want it, you could create a simple HttpModule that identifies requests for static content and calls:

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires()
```